# How to correctly disable timeout in Node.js http servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, timeout

I have a Node.js server that receives web requests from browsers. Now, some connections should stay open for a long time, potentially even forever - even if there is no data currently sent.

By default, http servers in Node.js have a timeout of 120 seconds, but I can disable that: According to the Node.js documentation, this is possible by [calling `setTimeout` and set the timeout to `0`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_settimeout_msecs_callback).

So, basically it looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.setTimeout(0);
  // ...
}).listen(3000);
```

If I run this, it seems to work, but I wonder if this really is all I need to do. Are there any settings in the browsers, any HTTP headers, … that could influence this behavior?

Comment: There is a draft spec for a `Keep-Alive` header that you might use to inform your client if needed, http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-01.html#keep-alive Cannot find anything newer though